# Error in connecting my ip address to flask server- ubuntu ipython

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, ipython

I am trying to connect my own server with the IP address created by amazon ec 2 instance. However, whenever I put this code, I get an error message. The code is:

```
from flask import Flask, request


visitor_counter = 0
webserver = Flask("MyFirstWebServer")

import datetime
import time

@webserver.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # stop_server()
    return 'Hello James, it is now ' + str(datetime.date.today()) 


@webserver.route('/testSU')
def hello_su():
    # stop_server()
    global visitor_counter
    visitor_counter += 1
    return 'Hello! You are visitor #{i}'.format(i=visitor_counter)

def start_server():
    global visitor_counter
    visitor_counter = 0
    webserver.run(host='aaa.bbb.cc.ddd', port=5000)
    return

def stop_server():
    shutdown_after_request = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    shutdown_after_request()
    return

start_server()
```

The error message that I get is "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address". This is the specifics of the error message that I get when I run the python notebook:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2dda11743df7> in <module>()
----> 1 start_server()

<ipython-input-1-dcbe603433f4> in start_server()
     30     global visitor_counter
     31     visitor_counter = 0
---> 32     webserver.run(host='aaa.bbb.cc.ddd', port=5000)
     33     return
     34 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, **options)
    839         options.setdefault('use_debugger', self.debug)
    840         try:
--> 841             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    842         finally:
    843             # reset the first request information if the development server

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py in run_simple(hostname, port, application, use_reloader, use_debugger, use_evalex, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type, threaded, processes, request_handler, static_files, passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
    706                           reloader_type)
    707     else:
--> 708         inner()
    709 
    710 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py in inner()
    668                           processes, request_handler,
    669                           passthrough_errors, ssl_context,
--> 670                           fd=fd)
    671         if fd is None:
    672             log_startup(srv.socket)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py in make_server(host, port, app, threaded, processes, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd)
    562     else:
    563         return BaseWSGIServer(host, port, app, request_handler,
--> 564                               passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
    565 
    566 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py in __init__(self, host, port, app, handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd)
    474                                       socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    475             port = 0
--> 476         HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
    477         self.app = app
    478         self.passthrough_errors = passthrough_errors

/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py in __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
    438         if bind_and_activate:
    439             try:
--> 440                 self.server_bind()
    441                 self.server_activate()
    442             except:

/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py in server_bind(self)
    136     def server_bind(self):
    137         """Override server_bind to store the server name."""
--> 138         socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
    139         host, port = self.socket.getsockname()[:2]
    140         self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)

/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py in server_bind(self)
    452         if self.allow_reuse_address:
    453             self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
--> 454         self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    455         self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
    456
```

I've used the terminal to see if there was any other server/program open on port 5000, but there was none. What might me the issue here?

Comment: `aaa.bbb.cc.ddd` probably doesn't map to an IP address assigned to the box. Most cases you want that set to either `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me Try it out

```
import os
from flask import Flask


__author__ = 'Rajshekhar Horatti'
app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "hello world"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

host should be `host = 0.0.0.0` and check out which port you have activated andassign that port